# How to use trackby when looping over custom components in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm looking to have `trackby:` for my `*ngFor` loops of custom components. [This is the example provided by angular](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description):

`<li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">...</li>`

But I'm looping over a list of custom components from an observable:
`<custom-component *ngFor="let item of (observable$ | async); trackBy: trackByFn"></custom-component>`,

When I try that, I get an error in the Angular compiler:
`Can't bind to 'ngForTrackby' since it isn't a known property of 'custom-component'.`

Is there a way to use `trackby` when looping over custom components in this manner?

Comment: Did you check you spelling of `trackBy`, because the error indicates that you wrote `trackby` instead of `trackBy`.

Comment: that was it! thanks